# gmaps4rails automatic geocoding not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, google-maps, gmaps4rails

I have a simple app running Rails3 & the gmaps4rails gem.
I have the map displaying successfully.

But, when I create a new User, the lat/long is not automatically generated like in the screencast.  What am I missing?

Here is my model code:

```
class Merchant < ActiveRecord::Base  
acts_as_gmappable  
 def gmaps4rails_address  
  "#{self.address}, #{self.zip} #{self.city}, #  {self.country}"  
 end  
end
```

I also can't enter in an address as simply "City, State".  I have to put in a complete address or I get an error.

Comment: show the code you put in your model

Comment: aha, I changed def to be self.address and it works now.  Do you think this will cause me trouble later?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There will not be any issue not using the example I provide in the wiki:

```
def gmaps4rails_address
  "#{self.address}, #{self.zip} #{self.city}, # {self.country}"  
end
```

This is just supposed to tell that you can customize it as you need.

So yes, it could simply be:

```
def gmaps4rails_address
  self.address 
end
```